# Find the position of a value in an array and use the position to get a value from array in other column

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, position

I have a table, where I would like to loop through the array in column "Type". If it contains 'cover', take the value from the "ID" array of the same position. And if there are 2 'cover' values, check the "style" column - if it is 'multi', ignore and take other value position.

| ID | Type | style |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [222, 345, 678] | ['leg','cover','cover'] | ['modern','multi','traditional'] |
| [989, 787, 125] | ['cover','hanger','comp'] | ['modern','modern','modern'] |

The desired output:

| ID | Type | style | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [222, 345, 678] | ['leg','cover','cover'] | ['modern','multi','traditional'] | 678 |
| [989, 787, 125] | ['cover','hanger','comp'] | ['modern','modern','modern'] | 989 |

I am using this code to get the position but I am stuck with the rest.

```py
df.select(df.Type, array_position(df.Type, "cover").alias('a_pos')).show()
```

Comment: Try: `df.withColumn("output", F.expr("ID[array_position(Type, 'cover')-1]")).show()`

Comment: @blackbishop thank you for the great help,  do you have any idea of how to select the position based on the second condition on style? like in row 1, we have two covers and I need to pick the last one since the style is "traditional'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a zipped array and filter out elements which you don't need.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([222, 345, 678], ['leg','cover','cover'], ['modern','multi','traditional']),
     ([989, 787, 125], ['cover','hanger','comp'], ['modern','modern','modern']),
     ([123, 234, 345], ['cover','hanger','comp'], ['multi','modern','modern']),
     ([456, 567, 678], ['couch','hanger','comp'], ['modern','modern','modern'])],
    ['ID', 'Type', 'style'])
```

Script:

```py
filtered = F.filter(
    F.arrays_zip('ID', 'Type', 'style'),
    lambda x: (x.Type == 'cover') & (x.style != 'multi')
)
df = df.withColumn('output', filtered[0].ID)

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---------------+---------------------+----------------------------+------+
# |ID             |Type                 |style                       |output|
# +---------------+---------------------+----------------------------+------+
# |[222, 345, 678]|[leg, cover, cover]  |[modern, multi, traditional]|678   |
# |[989, 787, 125]|[cover, hanger, comp]|[modern, modern, modern]    |989   |
# |[123, 234, 345]|[cover, hanger, comp]|[multi, modern, modern]     |null  |
# |[456, 567, 678]|[couch, hanger, comp]|[modern, modern, modern]    |null  |
# +---------------+---------------------+----------------------------+------+
```